# F.lux resets every time it reaches the designated color temperature

Tags: 14.04

F.lux installed in Ubuntu 14.04 keeps resetting the color temperature every time it reaches the color I chose. It goes on and on in an infinite cycle.

`/tmp/fluxlog.txt` doesn't show any issues, but it keeps being overwritten with the same config.

Any tips on how to make it work correctly?